# .aba file format not understanding it

Tags: php, .net

Do you know about Australian Banker's Association (.aba) file format ? It is used for batch transactions which is quite similar to csv files. However, what I don't understand is, how is the columns separated from each other. For example, in csv files, we use like (,;) etc. Also I don't find a sample files. Here is one link that could help you help me fast if you don't know already.

http://www.cemtexaba.com/aba-format/cemtex-aba-file-format-details.html

Comment: http://www.anz.com/internet-banking/help/pay-transfer-business/multiple-pay-anyone/import-file/#step1

Answer (score 1):

> However, what I don't understand is, how is the columns separated from each other. For example, in csv files, we use like (,;) etc

It is similar to CSV but it is a plan text file consisting of strings and lines...

Here are some ready solutions

Symfony 2 bundle -> https://github.com/latysh/aba-bundle

php library -> https://github.com/simonblee/aba-file-generator

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple file format. Instead of thinking of it as a CSV file, which is delimited using some symbol, think of it as a string of characters.

So, if you have an ABA file then you can parse it using `fopen()` and `fread()`.

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('example.aba', 'rb');
$block1 = fread($fh, 1);
$block2 = fread($fh, 17);
$block3 = fread($fh, 2);
$block4 = fread($fh, 3);
// And so on...
```

Of course it would make sense to also have some mechanism that validates the data, and makes sure that the file is not corrupted, but this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but for other people coding for ABA file format, 
http://www.cemtexaba.com/aba-format/ has a sample file format.

And this site has a great explanation on each of the fields
https://github.com/mjec/aba/blob/master/sample-with-comments.aba but don't refer to it as your single source of truth.

As Sverri M. Olsen has mentioned, the columns are not specifically separated by a separator, instead they just stick to the length specified by the specification.